# atexit handlers on AWS lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class Service:
    def __init__(self):
        atexit.register(self.cleanup)
    def cleanup(self):
        print("cleaning up")
```

And my Lambda function looks like the following:

```
service = new Service()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # use service
```

Since I have declared service outside my handler, it will be used in subsequent warm starts.

But what happens when my execution environment shuts down? Will the atexit handler in my Service class get called? I did not find anything in the AWS documentation regarding this.

Comment: Agree this does not seem to be clearly documented. Have you tested this? Do you see the "cleaning up" log when the Lambda service terminates the execution environment?

Comment: @jarmod I did not see anything in the cloudwatch logs. Or are you talking about different log streams?

Comment: I did mean CloudWatch Logs (or wherever you send your Lambda function logs, but I assume that is CW Logs).